# CopyOrigin on Insert in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me what the CopyOrigin parameter of Insert is used for?
And what values it will accept?

I have included the vba help (which wasn't really that helpful):

> Inserts a cell or a range of cells
>   into the worksheet or macro sheet and
>   shifts other cells away to make space.
>
> expression.Insert(Shift, CopyOrigin)
>   expression    Required. An expression
>   that returns a Range object.
>
> Shift   Optional Variant. Specifies
>   which way to shift the cells. Can be
>   one of the following
>   XlInsertShiftDirection constants:
>   xlShiftToRight or xlShiftDown. If this
>   argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel
>   decides based on the shape of the
>   range.
>
> CopyOrigin   Optional Variant. The
>   copy origin.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It takes either of one parameter as given below.

```
Const xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove = 0

Member of Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin
```

and...

```
Const xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1

Member of Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin
```

Answer (score 23):

Adding to Lakshmanaraj's comments - it picks up the formatting option depending on where you are inserting cells & what formatting you wish to pick.

Lets say you have:
first row which has bold text,
second row has things in italic.
You select the 2nd row & execute the following expression:

```
Selection.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

The new row gets inserted between 1st and 2nd row & it picks formatting rules from the "row above" or "cells to the left of the cell".

In this case, the newly inserted cells will have text as bold without you setting it explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

You can Reference here :

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim XLApp As New Excel.Application()
Dim xWkBook As Excel.Workbook = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(YourInitialPath)
Dim xSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xWkBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

CurCell = xSheet.Range("G9:G11")
CurCell.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, CurCell.Copy())
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely misleading, there's no reason to put `CurCell.Copy()` inside `Insert` call as it doesn't even return anything but copies CurCell contents to clipboard later to be inserted by `CurCell.Insert()`

Comment: curcell is what ? range variable ? planet variable ? Name of your wife ?

Comment: this is not vba, you can't set a variable while using `DIM`. everything is 'syntax error' color flagged in VBE (exept the line with `range`).