# Excel macro VBA insert

Tags: vba, excel, insert, line

I am trying to write a macro using VBA to include a new line above the selection.
For it I am using the following:

`Sheets(1).Select
Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Insert`

But whenever I insert this new line Excel automaticaly copies the superior line format.
Is there a way to insert this new line copying **only** the sheet borders?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do that. My suggestion would be to do something like this after the `Insert`:

```
Sheets(1).Select
Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Insert
Rows("4:4").EntireRow.ClearFormats ' <--- ADD THIS
' Call a Sub, e.g. "FormatMyBorders", to format your borders,
' passing the row as a parameter.
FormatMyBorders(Rows("4:4").EntireRow) ' <--- AND THIS
```

There may be other "tricks" you can use. For example, copy/paste a temporary row from another location with the formatting you want at the location you want to insert a new row, then insert your new row (which will inherit the temporary row's formatting) and then delete the temporary row. It's probably much more fiddly than what I said above though and having a Sub to format the row borders as you want is probably a useful function for you in the long run.

Comment: I guess this way is easier. Thanks buddy.

Comment: FYI, this can be done on the original insert with the `CopyOrigin` parameter.  MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840310.aspx.  SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684531/copyorigin-on-insert-in-excel-vba